# VSC and .NET problems with obj folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I'm new to .NET (C#) and am trying to learn it through the Microsoft Learn platform, and I downloaded Visual Studio Code (VSC) to do it.

When creating my thing, I entered "dotnet build" into the terminal, and then have been using "dotnet run" to run my code.

However, I keep having problems with the automatically created obj folder. Here are two errors I've gotten on two separate occasions with it:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.203\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targ
ets(4790,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\net8.0\TestPr
oject.dll" to "bin\Debug\net8.0\TestProject.dll". The requested operatio
n cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open. : 'C:\U
sers\Public\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Csharp Projects\TestProject\bin\
Debug\net8.0\TestProject.dll' [C:\Users\Public\Documents\Visual Studio Co
de\Csharp Projects\TestProject\TestProject.csproj]
```

and

```
CSC : error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Csharp Projects\TestProject\obj\Debug\net8.0\TestProject.dll' for writing -- 'The requested operation cannot be performed on a fil 
e with a user-mapped section open. : 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Csharp Projects\TestProject\obj\Debug\net8.0\TestProject.dll'' [C:\Users\Public\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Csharp Projects\T 
estProject\TestProject.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

*After this one, I tried to delete the obj folder, but couldn't as it was "currently being used by something else". I then used cmd prompt to delete it. This worked, but now I'm having the former error, which is now not fixed by deleting the obj folder.

I understand that this is likely a build issue, but I don't understand C# enough yet to know what that means. How do I fix this, to make sure the obj folder stops having problems?

Comment: The obj file was never created so it cannot be copied to the bin folder.  I would do a clean build and then try again.  The compiler contains dependencies and only files that have changed get compiled.  First obj files are created from source files and then dll are created by linking the obj files together.  Most of the time errors like this occur when libraries have changed which require all the source files to get recompiled.  A clean build will force all files to get recompiled.  You can accomplish the same by deleting the bin folder and/or the obj folder.  Check Error List for errors.

Comment: Deleting BOTH the bin and obj files and running "dotnet build" again worked, and now it's running fine again. I anticipate I'll run into this issue again, though. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Whenever you update any libraries always do a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\net8.0\TestPr
> oject.dll" to "bin\Debug\net8.0\TestProject.dll"

This typically occurs when a process has a lock on the file. Sometimes it can be the IDE itself, though most of the time it's a left over process that hasn't been shut down.

> After this one, I tried to delete the obj folder, but couldn't as it was "currently being used by something else"

There are tools like Process Explorer you can use to detect which process has a lock on a file.

Download [Process Explorer from the official Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

1. Search for the File: Use the search feature (Ctrl + F) and search for the filename.
2. View Handles: Once you find the file, you can view the handles (Ctrl + H) to see which process has it open.